# Flutter and PostgreSQL for WEB and Mobile recomends ? (

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, dart

I want devlop using sql databases, for web mobile apps.
postgresql is recommended ?
any guide i can read?

Comment: you can't use POSTGRES with mobile apps, you have to develop an API using your favourite language or stack, I prefer Express, NodeJS and POSTGRES

Comment: Checkout [help/dont-ask] to understand what is a good question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

for client-side database you should go with a lightweight database like => sqflite or hive or shared prefs ,

but if you are talking about server-side you can use driver https://pub.dev/packages/postgres

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is a client side programming language designed to build UIs whereas postgres is a server side database. You will need to use a server side API language similar to nodejs or java to build the APIs that flutter based UI will talk to. The APIs will in turn talk to the postgresql db and return the response back to Flutter UI.

You can also use a completely different stack as well where you can use reactjs and react native for UI for web and mobile respectively and something like python or nodejs for backend to talk to your db. The possibilities are endless. In my opinion please research different tools for UI, APIs and databases respectively and choose what you are most comfortable with.

All the best.